# How to make XamDataGrid edit a cell only on the second click

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

I have an Infragistics `XamDataGrid` (using 2011.1 WPF), which I'd like to mimic the behavior of a file browser (Finder/Windows Explorer) or iTunes, where a single click selects a row, and a second click opens the field's editor. As I have it currently defined, a single click immediately begins editing the selected row. I defined my grid like so:

```
<ig:XamDataGrid>
    <ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <ig:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" RecordSelectorLocation="None" />
    </ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    <ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <ig:FieldLayout>
            <ig:Field Name="Name" Width="*" />
        </ig:FieldLayout>
    </ig:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</ig:XamDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you set the XamDataGrid’s FieldSettings’ CellClickAction to SelectRecord and create a Style for the CellValuePresenter and handles its PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event. In the handler you should check if the clicked Record is Active and if so you can start Edit mode. You can define the XamDataGrid like this:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid >
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="CellValuePresenter_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        </Style>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings CellClickAction="SelectRecord"/>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

And use the following event handler:

```
private void CellValuePresenter_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as CellValuePresenter).Record.IsActive)
    {
        (sender as CellValuePresenter).Editor.StartEditMode();
    }
}
```

Also I can suggest you write into Infragistics forums, when you have an Infragistics related question:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/default.aspx?GroupID=38

because it is easier for tracking and you will get an answer from an Infragistics employee.

Hope this helps you.